What is important? Thidhi or nakshatra for giving birth?
What is important to chose a child's birth time? Is it Thidhi or star?
If only star is good but not star then can we give birth to child? I am looking for good luck to baby with no or less struggles in life.
We consider the star only right while checking horoscope so I consider if star is good then no need to consider thidhi. .

Tithi and Nakshtra are only the two limbs of a day and there are 5 limbs in total (known as Panchanga of the day) ... It is extremely difficult to judge like that and give birth .. it is almost impossible to get all the Panchamga limbs favorable for a particular birth.
